# React SSR(Server Side Rendering) for SEO before login and after login Create React App (CRA). How to do this in one project folder?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I have a question, suppose there are two scenarios before login and after login:

**Before login**
Website will be SEO with next js or some other way. And has few pages like blog, blog details, about, contact, and products etc.

**After login**
Normal feature like post, post details with CRA(Create React App) setup.

My question is how do we setup the project with before login in SSR and after login. I don’t want SSR after login because there are lots of load on server for each features and functionality.
Is there any solution?

I have few article on isomorphic like https://hackernoon.com/get-an-isomorphic-web-app-up-and-running-in-5-minutes-72da028c15dd

**example starter kit project:** https://github.com/xiaoyunyang/isomorphic-router-demo

**Can we create both SSR and Create react app within one project setup?**

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an express server you can use [ssr-for-bots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssr-for-bots) middleware to apply ssr to certain routes only.

```
const ssrForBots = require("ssr-for-bots");

const defaultOptions = {
  prerender: [], // Array containing the user-agents that will trigger the ssr service | uses Regex
  exclude: ["/routesAfterLogin/"], // Array containing paths and/or extentions that will be excluded from being prerendered by the ssr service | uses Regex
  useCache: true, // Variable that determins if we will use page caching or not
  cacheRefreshRate: 86400, // Seconds of which the cache will be kept alive, pass 0 or negative value for infinite lifespan default 24 hours
};

app.use(ssrForBots(defaultOptions));
```

That way the paths before login will be SSR, and paths after login (let's say they all start with /app) will be excluded

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can, there are some articles about that topic:

[Upgrading a create-react-app project to a SSR + code splitting setup](https://medium.com/bucharestjs/upgrading-a-create-react-app-project-to-a-ssr-code-splitting-setup-9da57df2040a)

[Server-side rendering with create-react-app, code-splitting, preloaded data, React Router, Helmet, Redux, and Thunk](https://medium.com/@cereallarceny/server-side-rendering-in-create-react-app-with-all-the-goodies-without-ejecting-4c889d7db25e)

Comment: But in first article I can see it's saying "We’ve come a long way, but we managed to upgrade our simple CRA app to a full SSR + code splitting setup in just a few steps"
So is that before login after login setup. As I can see he convert the CRA app to SSR.

I can't view second article. Medium says to upgrade.